# Convert nested bold italic HTML tags to NSAttributedString

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, attributes, nsattributedstring

I am using this code to convert HTML strings to NSAttributedString using RegEx. The only problem I am having is with nested bold and italic tags. Is RegEx the correct way to do it?

Also I want to avoid using an HTML parser because all I need is Bold, Italic and Underline attributes and StrikeThrough if Possible.

Any suggestions?

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)applyStylesToString:(NSString *)string searchRange:(NSRange)searchRange {

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[StylesConfig regularLargeFont] range:searchRange];

    NSDictionary *boldAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [StylesConfig regularBoldLargeFont] };
    NSDictionary *italicAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [StylesConfig regularItalicLargeFont] };
    NSDictionary *underlineAttributes = @{ NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @1};
    NSDictionary *strikeThroughAttributes = @{ NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName : @1};

    NSDictionary *replacements = @{
                                   @"<b>(.*?)</b>" : boldAttributes,
                                   @"<i>(.*?)</i>" : italicAttributes,
                                   @"<u>(.*?)</u>" : underlineAttributes,
                                   @"<s>(.*?)</s>" : strikeThroughAttributes
                                   };

    for (NSString *key in replacements) {

        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:key options:0 error:nil];

        [regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:searchRange usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
            NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];

            [attributedString addAttributes:replacements[key] range:matchRange];

            if ([key isEqualToString:@"<b>(.*?)</b>"]) {
                [self makeBoldItalic:attributedString matchRange:matchRange font:@"SourceSansPro-It"];

            } else if ([key isEqualToString:@"<i>(.*?)</i>"]) {
                [self makeBoldItalic:attributedString matchRange:matchRange font:@"SourceSansPro-Semibold"];
            }
        }];
    }
    [[attributedString mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<b>" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
    [[attributedString mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"</b>" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
    [[attributedString mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<i>" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
    [[attributedString mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"</i>" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
    [[attributedString mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<u>" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
    [[attributedString mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"</u>" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
    [[attributedString mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<s>" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
    [[attributedString mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"</s>" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];

    return attributedString;
}

- (void)makeBoldItalic:(NSMutableAttributedString *)attributedString matchRange:(NSRange)matchRange font:(NSString *)font {

    [attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

        UIFont *oldFont = (UIFont *)value;
        if ([oldFont.fontName isEqualToString:font]) {

            [attributedString removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
            NSDictionary *boldItalicAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [StylesConfig regularBoldItalicLargeFont] };
            [attributedString addAttributes:boldItalicAttributes range:matchRange];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: What kind of nested tags causes you issue? Do you have a example that doesn't work correctly?

Comment: "This is <i><b>italic and bold</b></i> text" -> This doesn't work while this one does -> "This is <b><i>italic and bold</i></b> text"

Comment: I tried your code with your two NSString tests. It passed. The big difference that I've done is that instead of changing the font, I put `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` for bold, and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` for italic. It worked. I guess that your font test is wrong. If you didn't applied yet a Bold Font, I don't understand how it's supposed to apply a italic font.

Comment: @Larme background and foreground colors are working, but the only problem is with Bold and Italic text at the same time or in the same string. The problem is that making a font bold and then italic doesn't work (you have to apply BoldItalic font which is a separate font).

Comment: @Larme I specifically need bold and italics.

Comment: What does returns `BOOL bold = ([UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Semibold" size:10].fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold)` and `BOOL italic = ([UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-It" size:10].fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits &UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic)` ? Same for the one which is Bold AND Italic at the same time (`regularBoldItalicLargeFont` if I understood)?

Comment: @Larme can you post the code please? Also post this as an answer, I cannot understand this in comments without code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that Bold and Italic (and other attributes) are part of the font, unlike underlining. iOS doesn't give a "fake bold" or "fake italic" like Photoshop can do for example.

So, I guess from your `StylesConfig` class utilities that you have:
`boldFont`, `italicFont` and `boldItalicFont`.

```
boldFont = [StylesConfig regularBoldLargeFont]; //SourceSansPro-Semibold
italicFont = [StylesConfig regularItalicLargeFont];//SourceSansPro-It
boldItalicFont = [StylesConfig regularBoldItalicLargeFont];//SourceSansPro-SemiboldIt (or something like this)
```

So to change the font, expecting that the font in its `symbolicTraits` `fontDescriptor` contains the correct one, you can do something like that:

```
-(void)boldText:(NSMutableAttributedText *)attributeString forRange:(NSRange)range
{
    [attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    UIFont *currentFont = (UIFont *)value;
    if ([[currentFont fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits] & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold)
    {
        NSLog(@"Font is already bold);
    }
    else
    {
         UIFont *newFont = [self boldFontFromFont:currentFont];
         [attributedString addAttribute:newFont range:range];
    }
    }];
}

-(void)italicText:(NSMutableAttributedText *)attributeString forRange:(NSRange)range
{
    [attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    UIFont *currentFont = (UIFont *)value;
    if ([[currentFont fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits] & UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic)
    {
        NSLog(@"Font is already italic);
    }
    else
    {
         UIFont *newFont = [self italicFontFromFont:currentFont];
         [attributedString addAttribute:newFont range:range];
    }
    }];
}

-(UIFont *)boldFontFromFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    if ([[currentFont fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits] & UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic)
        return boldItalicFont;
    else
        return boldFont;
}

-(UIFont *)italicFontFromFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    if ([[currentFont fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits] & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold)
        return boldItalicFont;
    else
        return italicFont;
}
```

In your current code:

```
if ([key isEqualToString:@"<b>(.*?)</b>"]) 
{
    [self boldText: attributedString forRange:matchRange];
}
 else if ([key isEqualToString:@"<i>(.*?)</i>"]) 
{
    [self italicText: attributedString forRange:matchRange];
}
```

If your font doesn't pass the `symbolicTraits` tests, you may have to look into the `UIFont` `fontName` and check if its Bold, Italic, or BoldItalic.

**Note:**
I didn't test the code, I write it only here, I don't even know if it compiles, but that should give you the whole idea.

Comment: What do you mean about your "StylesConfig class"? Should I make that class?

Comment: @MrMartin: Not necessarily. From the author code, `StylesConfig` seems to be a singleton or assimilated to provide just the UIFont corresponding accessible from everywhere.